# Kendo UI Virtualization grid with Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-kendo, kendo-ui-grid

I am fiddling with Kendo UI and Knockout and I can't seem to set grid to work in virtualization mode (single page, load 10 rows, and load more as the user scrolls). Was anyone able to do that or is this impossible with local data?

EDIT: What I have tried so far at jsfiddle.net/rTtS9/5/

Comment: show us what you have tried so far .

Comment: Sure, link is here: https://jsfiddle.net/rTtS9/5/ So i want to display 5 out of 21 rows but when i scroll down i want other 5 to load with knockout.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Did you look at the [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-local-data) and [API](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/grid) documentation? One of your mistakes is that the grid does not have a `pageSize` property. Hint: It's `dataSource` and `pageable` properties do.

Comment: Like this then? https://jsfiddle.net/rTtS9/8/ It seems that Kendo doesn't play well with KO in terms of updating, notice the grid data does not load properly (id column), when you go all the way down and then back again.